# How can I restrict an iterator to return only instances of a subclass?

Tags: java, iterator

I have some base class that implements iterable

```
public class EntityCollection implements Iterable<Entity> {

    protected List<Entity> entities;

    public EntityCollection() {
        entities = new ArrayList<Entity>();
    }

    public Iterator<Entity> iterator() {
        return entities.iterator();
    }

    ... etc
```

This is subclassed.

```
public class HeroCollection extends EntityCollection {

    public void doSomeThing() { ... }
```

I would like to do the following:

```
HeroCollection theParty = new HeroCollection();
theParty.add(heroA);
theParty.add(heroB);
for (Hero hero : theParty){
    hero.heroSpecificMethod();
}
```

But this fails at compile time, because the iterator is returning entities, not heroes.  I am looking for some way to restrict the list such that it can contain only the types of the subclass, so that I can call methods which are specific to the subclass on the result of the iterator.  I know it must use generics somehow but I can't seem to figure out how exactly to structure it.

Comment: Hero should be extending Entity.  Then, make an arraylist of heroes.  Unless there's some special property of hero collections you haven't told us about.

Comment: @RobertHarvey As noted in example, a HeroCollection would provide additional methods beyond those in EntityCollection.  It was suggested below that perhaps this is a bad idea, but I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest making `EntityCollection` generic.

```
public class EntityCollection<T extends Entity> implements Iterable<T> {

    protected List<T> entities;

    public EntityCollection() {
        entities = new ArrayList<T>();
    }

    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return entities.iterator();
    }

    ... etc

public class HeroCollection extends EntityCollection<Hero> {
    ...
}
```

Then, HeroCollection's iterator method will return an Iterator<Hero>

(Also note: the way you're designing your collections (with separate methods for specific types of collections) *suggests* that your code *may* be poorly designed. However, if so, that's a separate problem.)

Comment: Thanks, I think this is exactly what I was looking for.  Could you point me in the right direction as far as why it might be a bad idea for my subclassed collection to have specific methods?

Comment: @keypusher What are the methods you want to add, specifically?